# Javascript Facebook SDK Add/Delete comment on Users feed. Access Token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, access-token

I have a web app running on a local server that I can log into Facebook through.

I have been trying to add or delete comments from Posts are made by me and on my timeline.

When I try to execute the `FB.api()` call I get a failed response saying that I need a Page Access Token. The thing is, I've been looking around a lot and have seen nowhere a mention of a Page Access Token for a specific Persons profile.

Through experimenting I've been able to:

- Get a Page Access Token for a non-profile Page that I own
- Add/Delete Comments/Posts on that non-profile page
- Add/Delete Posts made by the app on my profile
- Display all Posts/Comments on my profile

What I want to do:

- Be able to delete/add comments on Posts on MY profile

What I've tried:

- GET request for `{my-id}?field=access_token`. I figured that if it worked for a non-profile page, it would work for my profile. It didn't work.
- A lot of googling

My Assumptions:

- I need a Page Access Token for my own profile if I want to add/delete things that were not made by the app
- A Page Acess Token for a profile exists.

Below is an example of a FB.api call that would return a response saying:
"Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens"

```
     FB.api(`${comment_id}`, 'DELETE', function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

I really just need someone to give me some concrete answers.

Comment: You can not comment in the name of a user any more.

Comment: Thank you so much. Kind of a weird thing to ask for in a project for a job interview huh.